# How to create three level relationship in sql?

Tags: sql

which is the best way to create a relationship between three tables, for example Customer has companies and those companies have branches. I need to know how you should create the keys of these three tables. The first would have CustID, the second table CustID and CompanyId and last one CustID, CompanyId and BrnchId.
There is a better way?

Comment: Customer -> companies -> branches.  No need for the double link stuff.  You could link a branch back to a customer through companies.

Comment: The relationship between the customer and the company is owned, according to use cases, there is customer first, then create businesses, which can not exist without the client and the branches can not exist without the business. Those are the rules.

Answer (score 1):

The Branch is not related to the customer. Neither is the Company really (well, the company does not rely on the individual customer to exist). You'd probably want to normalize out so there is a customerToCompany link table (so a customer can have many companies and a company can have many customers), the company to branch MAY be a one to many, depending on your use-case. Each main table has one PK (natural or surrogate, depending on the nature of your data) and the link tables contain the FKs.

Comment: The problem showed up because I need to get all branches of the client's business. I'm using EF4 and Repositories created using the interface IObjectSet <T> without the relationship that I mentioned at the beginning, I encounter a more complex query scenario